# Avoiding SQL injection in Flask SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql-injection, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to take the username from a login field after submission to query my SQL Alchemy database.  In the past I used things like the following:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.get("username"))
```

However this was in CS50 and I am now using SQL Alchemy and want to know how to use a similar ":username" statement.  So far this is all I have:

```
userinfo = User.query.filter_by(username= :username).first(), username=request.form.get("username")
```

This does not work.  I am using the documentation found here http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/ to help write this statement.  I am getting an error for invalid syntax.  The User class is set up like the "simple example" from http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#models but does not have the **repr** function.

Comment: Possibly: `userinfo = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form.get("username")
).first()`

Comment: I could use this but I am trying to avoid any cases of SQL injection.  I know SQL Alchemy is supposed to have a feature to help prevent injection but I want to try and write the best code regardless.